# Sharing an "Unavailable" layout

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I am writing a document, on which I work on several computers, and also with a colleague. The document uses a certain article layout that by default is unavailable on LyX.

The [LyX wiki page](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts) says that, in order to make it available, I have to do a certain system-specific installation (download relevant files, put them in OS-specific folders, etc.). However, this means that me and my colleague have to do the same installation procedure on every computer, which is very time-consuming.

Is there a better way to use an "unavailable" layout, that does not require system-specific installation? For example, is it possible to bundle all required files with my LyX file, so that I can send them to my colleague, and he puts them on the same folder, and it just works, with no installation?

Comment: As far as TeX files, if you are looking for one command to install TeX Live and the required files for all of LyX's examples and templates; and if you happen to use Ubuntu, take a look at https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, I do use Ubuntu, but unfortunately most of my colleagues use Windows...

Answer (score 2):

See the section "Local Layout" in Help > Customization.
Using that you can put anything you would normally have in a module or a layout file directly into the document (`Document > Settings > Local Layout`). To see an example, look at the `Help > Customization` manual and go to `Document > Settings > Local Layout`.

As far as OS-specific, external modules and layout files must go in your user directory, whose path is necessarily going to be specific to the platform. The general idea is the same, though. Go to `Help > About` to see where your user directory is, copy the modules and layouts to the corresponding folders, go to `Tools > Reconfigure` in LyX. Restart LyX.

If you want the exact same experience, consider installing a virtual machine.

Comment: I managed to put the layout locally, but, it still requires some files that I need to put in the user directory. I did this on my computer, but for my colleagues, this might be too technically difficult, so I am looking for a workaround.